# How to define the filepath to an external, "draged in" models in an OpenModelica model

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I have a basic model for a seesaw with in OpenModelica.

I then build up a new model called "bicycle" into which I drag the "seesaw"-model and use it as a component. "Seesaw" there represents the bicycle frame, onto which I put excitations from the ground etc..

Everything works fine during this work. But after closing the "bycycle" model and opening it again, openModelica doesn't find the seesaw-Model anymore, so that there's only an "place-holder" in the bycicle model where seesaw should be. The compiler gives the message "Class Seesaw not found in scope LoadAnalysis_Bicycle"

Inide the modelica code of "bicycle" seesaw is defined as:

`Seesaw seesaw(a = 0.5, b = 1)  annotation( Line(points = {{-8, -12}, {-8, -28}}, color = {0, 127, 0}));`

I estimate, that I need to give a path to the model seesaw, but can't figure out, how to do that.

I appreciate every help!

Best regards,

Daniel

I've tried to give the absolute as well as the relative filepath to seesaw, which resulted in "Problems are found in Modelica Text"

Answer (score 0):

Error message "Class Seesaw not found in scope LoadAnalysis_Bicycle" tells that seesaw model is not loaded.
Use menu option, file-->Open Model to load seesaw model

Comment: Thank you very much! 
I must admit I simply didn't figure out that I only need to load the submodel additionally. 
Is there a source code way to implement in the main model, that it automatically loads the sub model during execution?
I found `loadFile("path\to\my\file.mo")` which I don't get to work properly as OpenModellica warns that there is a error

Comment: create a package that includes all your models. upon loading the package expand the package to select the required model.